# i got a parent and i child form..but when i close the child it freezes..why?

Tags: vb.net

when i click the close button from the child form the child will move off to screen then close neatly..but when i close it through the parent close button the child will move off to screen then freezes...why ??? tnx in advance..

```
 Public Class ParentForm

   Private Sub Show_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button.Click
        ChildForm.MdiParent = Me
        ChildForm.Show()
   End Sub

   Private Sub Close_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Login.Click
        ChildForm.Refresh()
        Do Until Me.Location.X = ChildForm.Width
            ChildForm.Location = New Point(ChildForm.Location.X + 1, 250)
        Loop
        ChildForm.Close()
   End Sub
end class

Public Class ChildForm

   Private Sub ChildForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Location = New Point(0, 250)
        Me.Refresh()
   end Sub

   Sub anim() Handles Me.Shown
        Me.Refresh()
        Do Until Me.Location.X = 350
            Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + 1, 250)
        Loop
   End Sub

   Private Sub Close_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Close.Click
        Do Until Me.Location.X = Me.Width + 1000
            Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + 1, 250)
        Loop
        Me.Close()
   End Sub

end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a bug in this line:

```
 Do Until Me.Location.X = ChildForm.Width
     ChildForm.Location = New Point(ChildForm.Location.X + 1, 250)
 Loop
```

First of all, you are using the wrong object (`Me` instead of `ChildForm`). Also, your logic seems to be incorrect; if the child form is positioned further right than its width (e.g. if the child form has width 300 and its X position is 301), the code would go into an infinite loop. Try something more like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ChildForm.Width
    ChildForm.Left += 1
Next
```

That would shift it right by its width and maintain its vertical position on the screen.

Edit: Oops, it appears you want the parent form to close. In that case, use this instead:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.Width
    Me.Left += 1
Next
```

Comment: i'll try it..tnx mate ! :D